# Changing links in word doc from excel macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have this code in an excel macro that is intended to update links in my word documents.  Every quarter, I run a macro in an excel that is linked to 12 word docs that need to update from previous quarter to the current quarter.

OldFilePath is last quarters excel workbook location and NewFilePath is the current quarters excel workbook location and the locations of my word docs are in cells(c,33).

I have success with updating the first word doc but my macro crashes on updating of the second word doc links. I get an error message "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

I appreciate your help in resolving this issue.  Thanks.

EDIT:  As it turns out, I have some sort of "ghost link" in the word file.  When the macro runs, it counts 13 links to update but when I view the links in the edit links section of the word doc, I only count 12.  Has anyone seen this before?

```
Sub UpdateWordLinks()

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

oldFilePath = Range("AG17")
newFilePath = Range("AG18")

c = 3
Do Until c > 12

    Root = Cells(c, 33)
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(Root)
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath on the Field code
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To wDoc.Fields.Count
        wDoc.Fields(i).LinkFormat.SourceFullName = Replace(wDoc.Fields(i).LinkFormat.SourceFullName, oldFilePath, newFilePath)
    Next i
    
    'Update the links
    wDoc.Fields.Update
    
    wordApp.Documents.Save
    wordApp.Documents.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    
c = c + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You may have a link in a textbox, header/footer, etc. Your code won't find those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue - instead of editing links through the Edit Links function, I decided to write a macro that would be similar to manually doing alt+f9, find and replace links, refresh links.

```
Sub UpdateWordLinks()

Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

oldFilePath = Range("AG17")
newFilePath = Range("AG18")

c = 3
Do Until c > 12

    Root = Cells(c, 33)
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    Set wDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(Root)
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    'Use Replace to change the oldFilePath to the newFilePath on the Field code
    wDoc.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
    
    With wDoc.Content.Find
        .Execute Findtext:=oldFilePath, Replacewith:=newFilePath, Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
    wDoc.Fields.ToggleShowCodes
    
    wDoc.Fields.Update
    
    wDoc.Save
    wDoc.Close
    wordApp.Quit
    
c = c + 1
Loop

wordApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Problem solved. Doesn't matter if the number of links found in the edit links section and the word doc are not the same.